# Поиск слова по букве, и замена буквы

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, список

Нужно найти в списке слов все слова на букву `"в"`, и заменить букву `"в"`  на букву `"а"` во всех словах. Как это сделать, без разбивания каждого слова на буквы и замены по индексу. 
Пример:

Вход:

```
a=['рука', 'нож', 'ведро', 'Неаполь', 'Виктория', 'материк']
```

Выход:

```
a=['рука', 'нож', 'аедро', 'Неаполь', 'аиктория', 'материк']
```

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных и того, что хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: @MaxU,Вход : а=[рука, нож , ведро, Неаполь, Виктория,материк]
Выход:a =[рука, нож , aедро, Неаполь, aиктория, материк ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для списка:

```
import re

In [143]: print(a)
['рука', 'нож', 'ведро', 'Неаполь', 'Виктория', 'материк', 'бровь']

In [144]: new = [re.sub(r'^в', r'а', word, flags=re.U|re.I) for word in a]

In [145]: print(new)
['рука', 'нож', 'аедро', 'Неаполь', 'аиктория', 'материк', 'бровь']
#                                                              ^
```

Для строки:

```
import re

s = 'Нужно найти в списке слов все слова на букву "в", и заменить букву "в" на букву "а" во всех словах. Как ето сделать, без разбивания каждого слова на буквы и замены по индексу. Большое Спасибо!'
new = re.sub(r'\bв', r'X', s, flags=re.UNICODE)

print(new)
```

Результат:

```
Нужно найти X списке слов Xсе слова на букву "X", и заменить букву "X" на букву "а" Xо Xсех словах. Как ето сделать, без разбивания каждого слова на б
уквы и замены по индексу. Большое Спасибо!
```

Comment: , что означает  "142" вот здесь :"In [142]: Out[142]:"?

Comment: Это iPython (interactive Python) так маркирует и нумерует ввод и вывод. Кстати очень рекомендую - iPython (консольный вариант) или Jupyter (GUI в браузере) для работы с Python...

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы большую и маленькую "в" заменить на маленькую "а" в каждом слове в списке (не только в начале слова):

```
table = str.maketrans("вВ", "аа")
result = [word.translate(table) for word in a]
```

Или, не создавая новый список:

```
for i, word in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = word.translate(table)
```

Чтобы заменить "в" только в начале слова:

```
result = ["а" + word[1:] for word in a if word[0] in "вВ"])
```

Или, не создавая новый список:

```
for i, word in enumerate(a):
    if word[0] in "вВ":
        a[i] = "а" + word[1:]
```

Если буква у вас может более одной Unicode code point занимать, к примеру "ё" в NFD форме (буквальное сравнение):

```
if word.startswith(letter):
    a[i] = replacement + word[len(letter):]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replace = lambda s: 'а%s'%s[1:] if s.startswith('в') else s
list(map(replace, a))
```